# ¿Como hacer una sumatoria con el limite inferior y superior? For JAVA

Tags: java

Buenas tengo que hacer una calculadora en la que debo crear un método llamado sumatoria y por parámetro debo agregarle :

- limiteInferior : int
- limiteSuperior : int

El método debe devolver el resultado de sumar los números enteros que se encuentran entre el limite inferior y el limite superior (ambos inclusive).

Yo hice lo siguiente (es el último método) :

```
public class Calculadora {

  public int operador1;
  public int operador2;

  public Calculadora(){ 

  }

  public Calculadora(int operador1 , int operador2){

    this.operador1 = operador1;
    this.operador2 = operador2;
  }


public int sumar (){

    int suma = 0;

    return suma = this.operador1 + this.operador2;

}

public int sumar (int operador1 , int operador2){
    int suma = 0;

    suma = operador1 + operador2 ;

    return suma;
}

public int resta(){

    int resta = 0;

    return resta = operador1 - operador2;


}

public int resta(int operador1 , int operador2){

    int resta = 0;

    resta = operador1 - operador2;

    return resta;
}


public int multiplicacion (){

    int multiplicacion = 0;

    return multiplicacion = this.operador1*this.operador2;
}

public int multiplicacion(int operador1 , int operador2){


    int multiplicacion = 0;

    multiplicacion = operador1*operador2;

    return multiplicacion;
}

public double division (){

    double division = 0.0;

    return division= this.operador1 / this.operador2;


}


public double division (double operador1 , double operador2){

double division =0.0;

division = operador1 / operador2;

return division;

}

public int potencia (int base , int exponente){


      return (int) Math.pow( base , exponente);

}

public int sumatoria(int limite){

    int sumatoria =0;
    int menor = 0;


    for(int i=0 ; i<limite ; i++){ 

        if(i<limite){

            menor = i;


        }


        sumatoria +=menor;

    }


    return sumatoria;


}

public int sumatoria(int limiteInferior , int limiteSuperior){

int sumatoria1 = 0;
int sumatoria2= 0;
int total = 0;
int mayor = 0;
int menor=0;

for(int i = 0 ; i <=limiteInferior && i >=limiteSuperior ; i++){

if(i <=limiteInferior){

  menor = i;

}

if(i>=limiteSuperior){

  mayor = i ;

}

sumatoria1+=menor;
sumatoria2+=mayor;

}


return total=sumatoria1+sumatoria2;

}



}
```

Pero en el main me da 0 cuando en realidad creo que me deberia dar 55.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PruebaCalculadora{

public static void main (String [] args){



 Calculadora c1 = new Calculadora (852 , 654);
    Calculadora c2 = new Calculadora();

    System.out.println(c1.sumar());
    System.out.println(c1.resta());
    System.out.println(c1.multiplicacion());
    System.out.println(c1.division());
    System.out.println(c2.sumar(58 ,60));
    System.out.println(c2.resta(2019 , 1996));
    System.out.println(c2.multiplicacion (20 , 126));
    System.out.println(c2.division(98,4));

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

    int base = 0;
    int exponente = 0;
    int n = 0;


    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de n  : ");
    n = teclado.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++){

        System.out.println("Ingrese el exponente : ");
         exponente = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese la base : ");
        base = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println(c2.potencia(base , exponente));

    }

    System.out.println(c2.sumatoria(10));
    System.out.println(c2.sumatoria(5,10));


    }

}
```

Si me pueden decir que hice mal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo mejor es inicializar el contador con el límite inferior:

```
 public int sumatoria(int limiteInferior , int limiteSuperior){
  int sum = 0; 
  if (limiteInferior < limiteSuperior){
      for( int i = limiteInferior; i <= limiteSuperior; i++){
         sum += i;
      }
      return sum;
   } else {
     return -1; //error
   }


}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Genio :D , ahora salio espectacular , saludos!